# Is there implemented Access denied path in Blazor app

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there build in `AccessDeniedPath` feature in Blazor apps.
My app using role based Authorize approach for some components. eg (`@attribute [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]`)
In my App.razor

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <NotAuthorized>
            <h1>Sorry</h1>
            <p>You're not authorized to reach this page.</p>
            <p>You may need to log in as a different user.</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorizing>
        <h1>Authentication in progress</h1>
        <p>Only visible while authentication is in progress.</p>
    </Authorizing>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

Requests falling in `NotAuthorized` whether they are from users without rights or anonymous (not authorized at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `context` that you can use to determine whether current user is authenticated.

For example:

```cs
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" >
    <NotAuthorized>
        @if(!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <p> You need Login! </p>  
        } else{
            <p> Sorry, the content here is not for you! </p> 
            @*or render or component like <AccessDenied /> directly *@
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorizing>
        <h1>Authentication in progress</h1>
        <p>Only visible while authentication is in progress.</p>
    </Authorizing>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```